# How to generate symbols inside a loop in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, symbols

I have a section of a web app that passes a hash of values like this for each of the `order_items` in an `order`.

Like this:

```
def example_method
  values = {
    amount_1: order_items.first.unit_price,
    item_name_1: order_items.first.unit_price,
    quantity_1: order_items.first.quantity,

    amount_2 order_items.second.unit_price,
    item_name_2: order_items.second.unit_price,
    quantity_2: order_items.second.quantity,
  }
end
```

I'm trying to generate a solution where I have a variable like `n = 1` and generate the symbols for each `order_item` using `n` like this:

```
def example_method
  values = {
    n=1
    order_items.each do |item|
      :"amount_#{n}" => item.unit_price,
      :"item_name_#{n}" => item.name,
      :"item_number_#{n}" => item.id,
      :"quantity_#{n}" => item.quantity,
      n += 1
    end
end
```

I tried this syntax outside of the loop and it works perfectly to generate the symbols using the variable, the problem is that I get a Syntax Error when the code is inside the loop:

How can I achieve this behavior inside my code?

What am I missing?

## #edit

Edit for a proposed solution:

```
values = {
  # The rest of static values on the hash...
}

n = 1

items = order_items.each do |item|
  {
    "amount_#{n}".to_sym => item.unit_price,
    "item_name_#{n}".to_sym =>  item.printer.name,
    "item_number_#{n}".to_sym =>  item.id,
    "quantity_#{n}".to_sym =>  item.quantity, 
  }
  n += 1
end

values.merge(items)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this

```
n=1
order_items.each do |item|
  "amount_#{n}".to_sym => item.unit_price,
  "item_name_#{n}".to_sym =>  item.name,
  "item_number_#{n}".to_sym =>  item.id,
  "quantity_#{n}".to_sym =>  item.quantity,
  n += 1
end
```

## #edit

```
items = order_items.each do |item|
  "amount_#{n}".to_sym => item.unit_price,
  "item_name_#{n}".to_sym =>  item.name,
  "item_number_#{n}".to_sym =>  item.id,
  "quantity_#{n}".to_sym =>  item.quantity,
  n += 1 
end

old_hash.merge(items)
```

maybe you could running this and merge with outside hash

## edit 2

you can install gem 'pry' to a better debug solution. For more info check this videos [RailsCast Pry Debug](http://railscasts.com/episodes/280-pry-with-rails)

```
values = {
  # The rest of static values on the hash...
}

n = 1

items = order_items.each do |item|
  {
    "amount_#{n}".to_sym => item.unit_price,
    "item_name_#{n}".to_sym =>  item.printer.name,
    "item_number_#{n}".to_sym =>  item.id,
    "quantity_#{n}".to_sym =>  item.quantity, 
  }
  n += 1
end
binding.pry # this will able a ruby shell prompt and you can execute your code and analyse the values
values.class # in pry prompt
items.class # in pry prompt
values.merge(items)
```

#### #edit 3

@items = {}

```
order_items.each do |item| 
  @items = { 
  "amount_#{n}".to_sym => item.unit_price, 
  "item_name_#{n}".to_sym => item.printer.name, 
  "item_number_#{n}".to_sym => item.id, 
  "quantity_#{n}".to_sym => item.quantity} 
   values = values.merge(@items) 
   n += 1 
end
```

Comment: Tried this but still get a Syntax Error, added a bigger picture code, since I didn't mention previously that this happens inside a hash.

Comment: This seems to have worked! although now I am getting this TypeError: "no implicit conversion of Array into Hash" any thoughts on how to solve this?

Comment: Show the variables items and old_hash for me

Comment: please remove the brackets { } of .each.

Comment: I added them because without them I get this SyntaxError: `syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting keyword_end "amount_#{n}".to_sym => item.unit_price,`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120897/discussion-between-breno-perucchi-and-jorge-cuevas).

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the new symbol syntax with interpolation, it has to be the old one. Also, mutating an index inside the loop is a bad practice in general in Ruby, use `each_with_index` instead:

```
order_items.each_with_index do |item, index|
  {
    :"amount_#{index}" => item.unit_price,
    :"item_name_#{index}" => item.name,
    :"item_number_#{index}" => item.id,
    :"quantity_#{index}" => item.quantity,
  }
end
```

Comment: This solution did work, but I am getting a different syntax error: "syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting =>", what is this error?

Answer (score 0):

Syntax as such

```
amount_1: 1
```

is not valid as a key value needs to be wrapped in `{}` to be a hash or when passed as arguments to a method call.

Also since you're interpolating a string you can do the following

```
:"amount_#{n}" => 1
```

If what you're aiming to do is return an array of hashes then you want to do the following

```
n=0
order_items.map do |item|
  n += 1
  { 
    :"amount_#{n}" => item.unit_price,
    :"item_name_#{n}" => item.name,
    :"item_number_#{n}" => item.id,
    :"quantity_#{n}" => item.quantity,
  }
end
```

Comment: This solution worked, but now I'm getting this syntax error: "syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting =>" if we can fix this detail I can mark as answered, the line highlighted on the error is the `end` of `do`.